# In regards to Commentaries by Origen Adamantius, what were "characteristics of divine inspiration" for authors that create church doctrines?

Tags: early-church, origen, divine-law

After reading works by Origen Adamantius regarding scepticism surrounding the divine inspiration of 1 Corinthians 7:17 & 2 Timothy 3:16 written by the apostle Paul, disciples might wonder if early church councils established textual validation for "divine inspiration" in authors that create church doctrines.

In the "Commentary on John" [Book 1] by Origen Adamantius, we read in section #5:

> Consider on this point the language of St. Paul. When he declares that "Every Scripture is inspired of God and profitable," does he include his own writings? Or does he not include his dictum, "I say, and not the Lord," and "So I ordain in all the churches," and "What things I suffered at Antioch, at Iconium, at Lystra," and similar things which he writes in virtue of his own authority, and which do not quite possess **the character of words flowing from divine inspiration**. "

[Early Christian Writings - Origen](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/origen-john1.html)

Origen seems to speculate the "divine inspiration" of Shaul / Paul the Apostle in the self-imposed remarks found in 1 Corinthians 7:17.

1 Corinthians 7:17 [KJV]
"But as God hath distributed to every man, as the Lord hath called every one, so let him walk. **And so ordain I in all churches**."

In **2 Timothy 3:16** [KJV], we read :

> [16] "All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness"

**In response to Origen Adamantius, what were "characteristics of divine inspiration" for authors of church doctrines?**

Comment: Edited only to demonstrate linking. Feel free to rollback if you wish.

Comment: Peter certainly accepted 'all' Paul's epistles as 'scripture'... _in **ALL** his epistles, speaking in them of these things; in which are some things hard to be understood, which they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the **OTHER** scriptures, unto their own destruction._ 2 Peter 3:16. KJV